# Unity Shader Material Only Activates when Clicked

Tags: unity, shaders

I am currently programmatically settings some shader textures, related to a Mesh Filter.  The Mesh Filter is using a standard shader, and I am merely generating and setting the Bump and Height maps, via code.

```
Sphere.materials [0].mainTexture = biome;
Sphere.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().materials [0].SetTexture ("_BumpMap", bump);
Sphere.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().materials [0].SetTexture ("_ParallaxMap", heightTexture);
```

This is fine.  The issue is that the shader only seems to activate itself once it is clicked in the inspector.  Is there some sort of Activate() function I need to call in order to apply the shader effects to the Mesh?

[image: example]

Notice in the example (this is running in Play mode), that the shader only activates once I click the expand button on the Shader in the inspector.

What is going on here?

Comment: It's because of the walking clock.

Comment: Haha, I said it wasn't a walking clock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, So taken from http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MaterialsAccessingViaScript.html :

> The Standard Shader has some extra requirements if you want to modify
>   Materials at runtime, because - behind the scenes - it is actually
>   many different shaders rolled into one.
>
> These different types of shader are called Shader Variants and can be
>   thought of as all the different possible combinations of the shader’s
>   features, when activated or not activated.
>
> For example, if you choose to assign a Normal Map to your material,
>   you activate that variant of the shader which supports Normal Mapping.
>   If you subsequently also assign a Height Map then you activate the
>   variant of the shader which supports Normal Mapping and Height
>   Mapping.

If you do not set a default image for the Height Map of your shader, it will not activate the shader feature.

By setting a default HeightMap (just a blank image for example), the Shader activates on run as expected.